# JS toggle between `display: none` and `display: flex`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS function for a responsive navigation with a burger button to hide and show the navigation when the screen is too small.

My problem is that even though the CSS style says display:none the links of the navigation are shown on load, after that the button works as expected and lets me toggle between `display: none` and `display: flex`. What is causing it to ignore the `display: none` when loading?

```js
function myBurger() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.navigation1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3rem 3rem;
  .logo img {
    height: 5rem;
  }
  i {
    display: none;
  }
  .navLinks {
    display: flex;
    a {
      padding-left: 2rem;
      align-self: center; //vertical align
      color: $secondaryColor;
    }
  }
}


/*responsive*/

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #icon {
    align-self: center;
    i {
      font-size: 3rem;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  .navLinks {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    display: none;
    .nav-link {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation1">
  <!--nav container -->
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <!--logo image -->
  </div>
  <!--burger menu -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="icon" onclick="myBurger()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="navLinks" id="navLinks">
    <!--links, no need to be put in a list -->
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS to your question.  See [mre].  It's difficult to tell exactly why your case isn't working without it.

Comment: We'd need to see your HTML too. But you'd either have to make sure myBurger() is called onload, or set #navLinks to display:none from the beginning

Answer (score 5):

The `x.style.display == 'none'` expression won't work because [the `HTMLElement.style` property only returns properties from the inline `style=""` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), *not* the effective or [*computed style*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

What you want is `getComputedStyle()`, which returns the *effective* style rules applied to that element.

```
function myBurger() {
    const el = document.getElementById( 'navLinks' );
    if( window.getComputedStyle( el ).display === "none" ) {
        el.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        el.style.display = ""; // unset flex, so it returns to `none` as defined in the CSS.
    }
}
```

That said, you don't need any JS to achieve this - [just use a `<label>` for a hidden `<input type="checkbox" />` with the `:checked ~`-trick](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/):

```css
#menuTrigger { display: none; }

#menuTrigger:not(:checked) ~ #navLinks {
    display: none;
}

#menuTrigger:checked ~ #navLinks {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation1">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo">
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="menuTrigger" />
    <label for="menuTrigger">
        <i class="fa fa-bars">Click me</i>
    </label>

    <div class="navLinks" id="navLinks">
        <!--links, no need to be put in a list -->
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is the CSS selector specificity, you will need to use this selector inside the media query:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {  
    // ... 
    .navigation1 .navLinks {
        display: none;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {  
    // ... 
    .navLinks {
        display: none;
        // ...
    }
}
```

So it will be more specific than the selector at the top:

```
.navigation1 {
  // ...
  .navLinks {
    display: flex;
    // ...
  }
}
```